# Why does auto return type lose move semantics in this example?

Tags: c++, templates, auto, c++17

I was watching the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ULX_VTkMvf8#t=48m28s) where Nicolai says that auto loses move semantics for this example:

```
template<typename Callable, typename... Args>
auto call(Callable&& op, Args&&... args) {
return std::invoke(std::forward<Callable>(op), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

I was wondering:

1. why is this the case?
2. does [guaranteed](https://jonasdevlieghere.com/guaranteed-copy-elision/) RVO kick in in
           this example? If so what is the point of worrying about move?

Comment: I think the issue with this code is that if callable returns a reference `call` will return an object constructed from that reference. So use of `auto` to declare a return type will make it forward "not so perfectly". And the video suggests to use `decltype(auto)` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think Nicolai could have just phrased it a bit better.

When you return by `auto`, your function returns a *value* (the type of which will be deduced). If `std::invoke` returns a pure rvalue or an xvalue, then of course the result of `call` will be constructed accordingly (by a move, if possible). We don't "lose move semantics" in that sense.

But when we return by value, that value object needs to be created. It can be created by a move, and under certain circumstances ([which aren't present here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.copy.elision)) it can be elided, but it must be created. Guaranteed copy elision doesn't allow us to cop out of creating this object.

That can be quite wasteful if `std::invoke` gives us back an xvalue (an rvalue reference to something). Why should we construct an object to return it?

That's why a slide or two later he says we should return by `decltype(auto)`. The deduction rules will then preserve the value cateogry of the the call to `std::invoke`:

1. If it returns a value, we are no worse off. Our own `call` will return a value (which it may create by moving the return value of `std::invoke`).
2. If `std::invoke` returns an lvalue(`X&`) or an xvalue(`X&&`), that will be returned as is, without creating another object by a copy or move.

Comment: ah, so he is talking about the fact that auto forces use to materialize reference that may be result of op(args...) into the value before returning it. :) tnx